# java 11 collect to map by keeping value unique

Tags: java-8, java-11, collectors

I have a specific json value as shown below,

```
{
 "record_id" : "r01",
 "teacherNstudents": [
                      {
                       "teacher" : {
                                    "name" : "tony",
                                    "tid"  : "T01"
                                   },
                       "student" : {
                                    "name" : "steve",
                                    "sid" : "S01"
                                   }
                      },
                      {
                       "teacher" : {
                                    "name" : "tony",
                                    "tid"  : "T01"
                                   },
                       "student" : {
                                    "name" : "natasha",
                                    "sid" : "S02"
                                   }
                      },
                      {
                       "teacher" : {
                                    "name" : "tony",
                                    "tid"  : "T01"
                                   },
                       "student" : {
                                    "name" : "bruce",
                                    "sid" : "S03"
                                   }
                      },
                      {
                       "teacher" : {
                                    "name" : "tony",
                                    "tid"  : "T01"
                                   },
                       "student" : {
                                    "name" : "victor",
                                    "sid" : "S04"
                                   }
                      },
                      {
                       "teacher" : {
                                    "name" : "henry",
                                    "tid"  : "T02"
                                   },
                       "student" : {
                                    "name" : "jack",
                                    "sid" : "S05"
                                   }
                      },
                      {
                       "teacher" : {
                                    "name" : "henry",
                                    "tid"  : "T02"
                                   },
                       "student" : {
                                    "name" : "robert",
                                    "sid" : "S06"
                                   }
                      }
                     ]
}
```

I am trying to generate a map like the one below,

```
[ {"S01", "T01"} , {"S05","T02"} ]
```

This is by removing all duplicate values and selecting only one teacher and student. The current code I wrote for this is

```
var firstMap = records.getTeacherNstudents()
                      .stream()
                      .collect(Collectors.toMap(tS -> tS.getTeacher().getTid(),
                                                tS -> tS.getStudent().getSid(),
                                                (a1, a2) -> a1));
return firstMap.entrySet()
               .stream()
               .collect(Collectors.toMap(Map.Entry::getValue, Map.Entry::getKey));
```

I believe this can be improved, by using `Collectors.groupingBy`. I am still working on it, but if anyone has any good idea on how to solve this, please share.

Comment: So you need a map associating a *teacher id* with the *id* of any of their *students*. And you've managed to generate such a map. Then what's the problem?

Comment: no, it just swaps the key and value

Comment: `I believe this can be improved, by using Collectors.groupingBy` - no it's **not**.

Comment: I want to do this in a single line.. I don't want to do the key and value swapping

Comment: You need the data to be grouped by *teacher id*, that inevitably requires creation of an intermediate map in which a *key* would be represented *teacher id*. This step can't be omitted.

Comment: And what if teachers happen to be associated with the same student? Is it possible? In such case, your code will fail.

Comment: In case if loosing some of the *teacher id* is not acceptable, you might consider changing the type of map to be `Map<String,List<String>>`.

Comment: I believe you are right, an intermediate map is needed. The student id and teacher id are unique and won't be repeated. `Map<String,List<String>>` is a good thought but I want to check whether everything can be done in a single line... Maybe I can do a map() and return a stream of entry set and filter the ones with duplicate ids

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Using Java 8 groupingBy**

You can try the below approach in order to have the **`Map<String,List<String>>`** or **`Map<String,Set<String>>`***(avoid duplicates)* where key of map will be the teacher id and value as List or Set of Students corresponding to each teacher.

I have used **`groupingBy`** feature from java 8 and did the grouping based on the tId and before collecting it, I have downstream it to List or Set of student Ids corresponding to each tId.

**Approach A:** **Map<String,Set< String >>** (Uniques)

```
data.getTeacherStudentMappingList()
                .stream()
                .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(x -> x.getTeacher().getTid(), LinkedHashMap::new,
                        Collectors.mapping(y -> y.getStudent().getSid(),Collectors.toSet())));
```

**Approach B :** **Map<String,List< String >>** (Non-uniques, duplicates)

```
data.getTeacherStudentMappingList()
            .stream()
            .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(x -> x.getTeacher().getTid(), LinkedHashMap::new,
                    Collectors.mapping(y -> y.getStudent().getSid(),Collectors.toList())));
```

*Here,*

- **`data`** is the converted object from the given json.
- **`LinkedHashmap::new`** is used to preserve the order of student data from the json in the output.
- **`collectors.mapping`** is used to convert the values corresponding to each key into the student ids.
- **`Collectors.toList()`** will collect the list of student ids in the list.
- **`Collectors.toSet()`** will collect the **unique** student ids in the set.

**Output:**

```
{T01=[S01, S02, S03, S04], T02=[S05, S06]}
```